# is ToXMLContentHandler thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, apache-tika

I am currently using Apache-Tika to parse my documents. While parsing the documents I am using AutoDetectParser, ToXMLContentHandler, Metadata classes of Apache Tika in this way:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
String filecontentInXMLFormat = handler.toString();
```

I have created the beans of AutoDetectParser, ToXMLContentHandler, Metadata using Springs, so the same class objects will be used when multiple documents are getting parsed through the same code flow.
So for example, if the second document comes in inside the code flow, will the "handler" object contain the data of the first document?

So, is the ToXMLContentHandler class "iorg.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler" and Metadata class "org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata" thread safe?

Comment: In almost all cases, you want fresh `Metadata` and `ContentHandler` objects for each document parsed

Comment: So that means its not thread safe?

Comment: You can have two different threads writing to the same one fairly safely, however they'd both need to be working on the same document. I don't think thread safety is your problem here, from what you have described, it is that you need a fresh one of those per document parsed!